# How to fix deprecated nuget-package NLog.Config

Tags: nuget-package, nlog, deprecated, visual-studio-2022

Just noticed that in my list of Nuget packages, that "NLog.Config" is marked as deprecated:

[image]

Is it safe to simply delete the package?

This particular application is for Google Calendar API usage.

---

I should have looked more closely at my code. I removed the package and now my tool won't compile. I have code like:

```
Imports NLog
Private m_logger As NLog.Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
```

And 10 instances of calls like:

```
m_logger.Error(ex, "RESULT_FAILED_OAUTH")
```

How to resolve now that `NLog` is deprecated?

Comment: [NLog.config](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config)-nuget-package is safe to remove, and one is encouraged to remove it. It became obsolete when Microsoft introduced `<packagereference>`-syntax. Now the [NLog.config](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config)-nuget-package actually causes issues because it can reset the NLog.config-file on application-publish (Same story can also seen on the nuget-package-page)

Comment: @RolfKristensen My project is now broken as I was using `NLog` directly. Is there a safe alternative?

Comment: @RolfKristensen I installed `NLog`. Now compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NLog.config](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config)-nuget-package is safe to remove, and one is encouraged to remove it. It became obsolete when Microsoft introduced `<packagereference>`-syntax.

Now the [NLog.config](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config)-nuget-package actually causes issues because it can reset the NLog.config-file on application-publish (Same story can also seen on the nuget-package-page)

Just replace it with [NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog)-nuget-package, if you don't have it installed already.